# Umbraco Structured URL

Tags: umbraco

I have created a multilingual site using Umbraco with the following structure:

- Content

  - en

    - home
    - profile
    - contact
  - esp

    - home
    - profile
    - contact

When I look at the URL's for *home* for both *en* and *esp*, they look identical like this:

`www.mydomain.com/home.aspx`

How do I make them look like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/en/home.aspx
www.mydomain.com/esp/home.aspx
```

I have the same problem for *profile* and *contact* pages as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the treeview for the site structure on the left of the CMS (although you fail to specify a version and I understand (to my knowledge) that the UI has undergone significant work since the last time I used it, say, up to version 5, but I don't expect this to be *too* different), right-click the root language/culture node (e.g. `en`) and you should see an option to set the domain.

Specify the URL (e.g. `www.mydomain.com/en/`) and save, whatever - that should do the trick.

However, your structure appears a little redundant given that the root node of each culture-specific site could serve as the home page for that version - generally the standard in Umbraco.

Another note is this. You can [make your URLs more "friendly" by using `umbracoUseDirectoryUrls`](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/setting-up-umbraco-for-friendly-urls), as set in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to associate a hostname and a language for every top-level language node (*en* and *esp*):

- Right-click on *en*
- Set the hostname to `www.mydomain.com/en`
- Set the language to en-US or en-UK
- Save those settings
- Do the same for *esp* with `www.mydomain.com/esp` and *es-ES*

Answer (score 0):

I have found out...
in web.config there is a setting called:

```
<add key="umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath" value="true" />
```

which should be changed to false. everything will rock :)